# robot framework sphinx integration

Tags: python-sphinx, robotframework, autodoc

I am trying to figure out a way to do basically what sphinx [autodoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html) does but with robot framework tests and user-defined keywords. I've looked at sphinxcontrib-robotdoc and sphinxcontrib-robotframework and neither do quite what I'm looking for (to my knowledge).

My documentation folder (sphinx's root directory) is in the same location as the folders containing the robot framework tests and custom library:

```
robotframework_dir
-docs
-tests
-- some more folders related to tests
-libraries
-- some more folders containing custom keyword libraries
-etc.
```

My question is, is there any way to auto-generate documentation (which will be included in the test files with the [documentation] tag) and place it inside of the docs folder for sphinx to use?

Answer (score 0):

Robot framework offers already a tool to generate docs for your libraries and keywords the tool is lib doc :

http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tools/libdoc/doc/libdoc.html